# Behavior of GoogleConnectedSheet in case of error

Tags: google-apps-script

We are using a connected sheet to link BigQuery data to a spreadsheet.
We are updating the data on an hourly basis, but the linkage was failing at one point in time, and the linkage was not executed again at the next update point.
We are not updating the schema, so we think it is an error on the connected sheet side.

Please allow me to confirm the following specifications

- Specifications when the linkage of the ConnectedSheet fails
  ○  Is it necessary to perform the re-association manually?
  ○  Whether or not a notification email is sent. Since the error mail was not notified this time, please let us confirm the details of what is notified and what is not notified.
- Is there any way to check the record of linkage failure of the connected sheet other than by e-mail?

We contacted GoogleWorkspace but were unable to confirm details.
If anyone has any information, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.